# How do I open a "Acrobat X" document without the newest version?

Tags: pdf, file-format

When I open a certain PDF file I get the following error:

```
For the best experience, open this PDF portfolio in 
Acrobat  X or Adobe Reader  X, or later.

Get Adobe Reader Now!
```

I have Foxit Reader 5.1.4 and Adobe Reader 8.3.1. Neither will open it at all, except for this error message. Brief google-ing showed that a similar thing can happen with version 9.

```
For the best experience, open this PDF portfolio in
Acrobat 9 or Adobe Reader 9, or later.
```

Apparently Adobe, in their wisdom, has invented a new format that in not backwards compatible, and someone saved this document in the non-backwards compatible mode. Spiffy-do for them. Great for Adobe in theory, but

1. I do not *want* to get the new version of Adobe.
2. I did try to download it, against my better judgement. The installer downloaded. I ran it. It failed to finish, and deleted itself as well so I couldn't just try again.

So now I am thoroughly against getting the new version, or using Adobe Acrobat at all. Good move Adobe.

Is there another way to convert this to something I can read? My first thought is to find someone who has Adobe Acrobat X, have them open it, and save it in a backwards compatible format. But I'd rather not involve others, I want something I can do myself for the next time this happens.

I tried uploading to Google Docs, to see if they would magically parse the document so I could read it in the web format. That had the same results, the dumb message/advertisement.

Since this is not something that I *have* to have, if I can't read it without version X, I will just go without it.

Comment: I'm also seeing this within Chrome at the following URL:
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/kb/docDisplay/?docId=c03985179

Most annoying!

Comment: Have you tried some other viewers independent of Adobe? Can you try some (at least evince; that's open-source).

Comment: @PeterJenkins: When I open that (my system uses okular via kpart plugin) I see that message, but I also see a message "This document has embedded files. Click here to see them." and when I click that it shows me two `.pdf` files and can save them and when I do and they can be shown without problem.

Comment: @JanHudec thanks for the tip ... I'm mainly using Linux so I might give Okular a try next time.

Comment: Just to confirm that Okular can open these embeded pdf's within pdfs. There is probably a command line tool for this somewhere ... at least I've extracted embedded images before to great success.

Comment: The penchant for Adobe's installers to delete themselves when you run them irritates me to no end.  If I wanted it deleted _I_ would delete it!

Answer (score 16):

I'm 99% sure PDF's like these are assembled as portfolios of multiple standalone pdfs in Adobe Acrobat.

- [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) (windows only), bookmarks sidebar (F12) lists embedded documents.
- [evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) (gnome), sidebar (F9) and choose attachments from the heading dropdown menu.
- [okular](http://okular.kde.org/) (kde), untested but others say it works.
- [pdftk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftk) extract all pdf embedded attachments: `pdftk <filename> unpack_files output .`
- [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) extract all pdf embedded attachments: `pdfdetach -saveall <filename>`

Comment: On Mac OS X Yosemite, I used homebrew to install pdf-tools. This allowed pdfdetach -saveall input.pdf, which gave me access to all of the contents, which could then be opened in Preview.

Comment: Just seconding that `pdftk`'s `unpack_files` does the trick...

Comment: It doesn't work in evince 3.12 (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04), but does reportedly work in 3.18.2 (Xenial)

Comment: Evince advice also works in Atril. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on Okular. You can view the portfolio files in "File -> Embedded Files" and either extract them or open them directly from that menu.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say ditch Adobe Acrobat completely--it is just a waste of time, 
and they are trying to generate more sales with this
new "feature" (read "bug").

You can bypass this with a conversion to ps and back:

```
pdf2ps file.pdf
ps2pdf file.ps
```

Or, avoiding creation of an intermediary file by piping pdf2ps output to ps2pdf input:

```
pdf2ps file.pdf - | ps2pdf - converted_file.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

PDF.js allows opening multi-file PDF's. It's the built-in PDF reader of Firefox, but it's also offered as a web app.

1. Visit the PDF.js web app at https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html
2. Click the "Open File" icon and select your file.
   [image: Open file]
3. Expand the left sidebar
4. Click the "Show Attachments" icon.
   [image: PDF Portfolio in Firefox]
5. Select one of the enclosed PDF's or other attachments to open the enclosed file.

Answer (score -4):

The simple answer is get Adobe X or another app like PDF Creator Pro to handle the problem file.  Most will have a cost associated where Acrobat reader X will not.

The event logs may indicate why the install failed and additional info on your Operating System might help get a better answer.

Consider that the version of Acrobat you have may have some significant security issues and that PDFs are a common malware vector.  Upgrading to something is likely a good idea to close a security hole.

Comment: Can the downvote be explained.  I would appreciate knowing where my answer fell short

Comment: When the question explicitly states getting Adobe X is _not accepted_, don't bother suggesting it. Joining the downvote.